# Why doesn't org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender create the archive files?

Tags: log4j

This is Log4j 1.2.17. I have `file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT/bin/log4j.properties` on the classpath. Its contents are:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, queuesLog
 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.queuesLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.queuesLog.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.queuesLog.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.queuesLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.queuesLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.queuesLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%M:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.queuesLog.File=C:/QEU/logs/queues.log
```

So when I saw that all of the archives (e.g. `queues.log.1`) are missing, I concluded that Log4j wasn't obeying this configuration file. I checked several things, whose details I don't believe are necessary for this question. Those checks told me that Log4j *should* be obeying the above configuration file. Finally, I learned about `-Dlog4j.debug`.

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT/bin/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT/bin/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, stdout, queuesLog].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%M:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "queuesLog".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "queuesLog".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%M:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "queuesLog".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:/QEU/logs/queues.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1MB].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
log4j: setFile called: C:/QEU/logs/queues.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "queuesLog" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j: rolling over count=1025467879
log4j: maxBackupIndex=10
log4j: Renaming file C:\QEU\logs\queues.log to C:\QEU\logs\queues.log.1
log4j: setFile called: C:/QEU/logs/queues.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
```

This confirms that `file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT/bin/log4j.properties` is in use. Furthermore,

```
log4j: Renaming file C:\QEU\logs\queues.log to C:\QEU\logs\queues.log.1
```

is explicit, but the archive files aren't there!

`queues.log` grows until the operating system doesn't like it anymore, which happens at 4 GiB.